# Passing HTML text input to Facebook API javascript call

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a web app where user can input in a text box a URL, and it return in an alert box the FB data of the link (comment count and shares)

The fblogin part works perfectly. I want to basically use whatever the user put in textbox1 (id is url) in the fb.api replacing the current hard coded URL (http://www.google.com).

Another problem in that code is that, even when i use the hardcoded URL, and when i change it and update the file using FTP, it ALWAYS shows me results that is from one of the URLs i ran before, and not the currently input one (in that example it is google.com).

You can see a live demo here: http://floralytics.com/fb/fbapi.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

 <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

 <input name="textbox1" id="url" type="text" />
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="testAPI(document.getElementById('url').value)" type="button" value="Execute" />

<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '470275149837189',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
 //   console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
   // FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     // console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        //'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    //});

//FB.api('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtNyJWKRtbo', function(response) {
//console.log(response);
//alert('# of fb comments: ' + response.share.comment_count);
//alert('# of fb Shares: ' + response.share.share_count);
//});


FB.api("http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com",
  function(response) {
      alert('# of fb comments: ' + response.share.comment_count);
alert('# of fb Shares: ' + response.share.share_count);
  }
);

  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So to help others, i found the answer. Simple use the following

```html
//set an id for your text box, and call your function. something like that:

<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="YOURFUNCTION()" type="button" value="Execute" />

//Then do the following inside the javascript
var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
FB.api("http://graph.facebook.com/?id=" + url,
function(response){
...
..
...
```

For the problem of showing same data, it turned out to be that you need to URIencode the URl first before pushing it. I used encodeURIComponent javascript